# How to block the public git accounts expect organization accounts on firewall

Tags: azure, github, networking, web-application-firewall, wvd

I want to block all the public git account access on firewall expect my organization account(ex-https://github.com/comanyname)
I want this for my Azure WVD environment, is there any other suggestions also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to do for now? And what worked for you and didn't work? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish
 Hi Mohamad 
I didn't tried yet, i am looking for this solution on WVD environment which is under a managed firewall.
Kindly let me know if you need any more details.